# LineString with UTM coordinate on d3

Tags: d3.js, gis, geojson

I'am trying to implement some mapping with d3. Some problem happen after i moved from using command d3.svg.line() to d3.geo.path() and restructure to Geojson.

I have drew line string section set on UTM coordinate zone 48N as following

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"02","properties":{"name":"LMC1"},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[
[375221,1.92031e+06],[375287,1.92027e+06],..]}},..]}
```

I set projection by using mercator

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator(),
path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
```

This result shown with complex line string
JavaScript console shown

```
Error: Problem parsing d="M521120.2777777778,111.9000492736892L620.2810464730694,...
```

Did i do something wrong with projection; or geo.path did not support UTM yet?
Does anyone have any idea?

You also see my example of this code on http://jsfiddle.net/agadoo/qNCcV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use UTM coordinates with `d3.geo` (yet). You have to convert them to e.g. a Mercator projection before passing the data to d3. This (and much more) is covered in [Mike's tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/).

Comment: I will change to lat/long. Very nice tutorial! Thank you very much.